# For the sum in the binomial theorem, what if the upper limit was different than n in the rest of the summand?

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

For the sum in the binomial theorem, what if the upper limit was different than n in the rest of the summand? Like this:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k}
$$
Does it have a closed form at all? Or even anything like where x or y equals 1 or something? Or is this the same as trying to find $\sum_{0}^{m}\binom{n}{k}$, where it's impossible?

Comment: The last  one you mention, $\sum_0^n\binom{n}{k}$, is very much possible. There is no known closed form for your main sum in "elementary" terms.

Comment: Assuming the latter sum is also meant to have an upper limit of $m$, notice that the former and latter are the same if $x=y=1$.

Comment: Yeah sorry, mistake on my part. The latter one was supposed to have m. And yeah, fair point. What do you mean by no known closed form in "elementary" terms?